# Как сделать выборку из всех объектов в mongo db, с помощью node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, mongodb

```js
mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/sandbox', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db('sandbox');

    db.collection('users').find({}, function (findErr, result) {
        if (findErr) throw findErr;
        console.log(result.name);
        client.close();
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

При запуске данного кода в консоли выводится: "undefind". Как сделать так, чтобы выводились в консоль все имена?

Comment: Попробуйте `result.map(m=>m.name)`

Comment: Безрезультатно.

Comment: Покажите, как попробовали.